# Send Friend request to a facebook user using Facebook Graph API 2.x

Tags: facebook, addition, friend

I want to send friend request from my app to any facebook user (who is not my friend but I have his app-scoped-facebook id.)

(Just kind of adding 'Add Friend' button in my app)

Is there any way to implement this in facebook API 2.0 and above

Answer (score 0):

Adding friends is not possible through the API

You can call `http://www.facebook.com/addfriend.php?id=[USER UID]`

Where `[USER UID]` is a valid facebook user id.

Answer (score 0):

I got one solution but don't know it will be deprecated or not  as it is of v1.0
But at present its working :)

FB.ui(
    { 
     method: 'friends', 
     id: fbid 
    }, 
    function(data){
     console.log(data);
    }
);

Comment: Which answers??? the link 'http://www.facebook.com/addfriend.php' is not loading and giving error...